# How do you change a UserControl Resource?

Tags: wpf

I have a usercontrol resource defined:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <System:Double x:Key="marginAndThickenss">3</System:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This is working great throughout this usercountol as the margin and thickness I need for different elements.

My question is, How can I change this variable during runtime?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Resources["marginAndThickenss"] = newValue;
```

use

```
FindResource("marginAndThickenss");
```

to get resource value

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  I guess it is working, however, it does seem to change the thickness or margins it is referring to.  Any ideas?

Comment: You whant change variable without changing control margins or thickness?

Comment: I think B-Rad means the setter property doesn't change as expected even thought the resource value successfully change during runtime. It seems like the resource value need to be loaded before window render the content. Set the resource in Windows_ContentRendered event should solve problem. However this trick still doesn't solve the problem when it is a UserControl.